# javascript web audio analyser : getByteFrequencyData at a precise time?

Tags: javascript, time, web-audio-api

Based on the web audio analyser API, I am creating an audio animation that draws images based on the real time frequency spectrum (like the classical bar graphics that move to the frequency of the sound, except that it is not bars that are drawn but something more complex).

It works fine, my only issue is that I am not able to stop the image at a precise time.
When I want to have it stopped at let's say 5 seconds, then some times it stops at 5.000021, or 5.000013, or 5.0000098, ...
and the problem is that the frequency spectrum (and so my image based on this frequency spectrum) is not the same at 5.000021, or 5.000013, or 5.0000098, ...
This means that the user when he wants to see the image corresponding to 5s, every time he sees a slightly different image, and I would like to have only one image corresponding to 5s (often the image is only slightly different at every try, but sometimes the differences are quite huge).

Here are extracts of my code:

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var soundmp3 = document.getElementById('soundmp3');
soundmp3.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
var audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(soundmp3);
var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize =   2048;
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.95;
audioSrc.connect(analyser);
audioSrc.connect(ctx.destination);
var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

function renderFrame() {
   if(framespaused) return;
      drawoneframe();
      requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame); 
    };

function drawoneframe(){
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
   // drawing of my image ...
 };

function gotomp3(timevalue){
  soundmp3.pause(); 
  newtime = timevalue;
  backtime = newtime - 0.2000;  
  soundmp3.currentTime = backtime;
  soundmp3.play();

  function boucle(){
   if(soundmp3.currentTime >= timevalue){     
     if(Math.abs(soundmp3.currentTime-newtime) <= 0.0001){
      drawoneframe();
      soundmp3.pause();
      soundmp3.currentTime = timeatgetfrequency;
      return;
     } else {
        soundmp3.pause();   
        soundmp3.currentTime = backtime;
        soundmp3.play();              
     };
   }      
   setTimeout(boucle, 1);    
  };
  boucle();
};


document.getElementById("fieldtime").onkeydown = function (event) {if    (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
    gotomp3(document.getElementById("fieldtime").value);
    return false;
  } 
  return true;
  };
```

Code explanation: if the user enters a value in the "fieldtime" (= newtime) and hits enter, then the I go first 0.2s back, start playing and stop when the currentTime is very close to newtime (I have to go back first, because when I go directly to newtime and stop immediately afterwards then the analyser.getByteFrequencyData does not yet have the values at newtime). With boucle() I manage to get it stopped at very precise times: if newtime = 5, then the time when drawoneframe(); is called is 5.000xx but the problem is that every time the user enters 5 as newtime, the image that is shown is slightly different.

So my question: has someone an idea how I could achieve that every time the user enters the same time as newtime, the image will be exactly the same ?

I am not quite aware at which times the soundmp3.currentTime is updated ? With a samplerate of 44.1kHz, I guess it is something like every 0.0227ms, but does this mean that it is updated exactly at 0, 0.0227ms, 0.0454ms, ...or just approximately ?
I thought about smoothing the analyser results, so that there are less variations for small time variations. Setting analyser.smoothingTimeConstant to a value close to 1 is not sufficient. But maybe there is another way to do it.
I do not need high precision results, I just would like that if a user wants to see the image corresponding to x seconds, then each time he enters x seconds, he sees exactly the same image.

Thank you very much for any help.
Mireille

Comment: The time update is base3d on the audio chunks received. You JS is really bad at timing because of the way JS event queue works. If the chunks are coming in at a certain size, then decoded from MP3, you cannot control the time update to be that precise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it seems that I can not stop the playing at a sufficient precise time to get always the same image. Maybe it is possible to do some kind of smoothing on the mp3 to have less variations for very small time variations ?

Comment: I was trying to pipe mp3 data through a websocket and then use 2 analyzers switching, but I couldn't do the timing.